# How to deploy APplets with no restrictions

Tags: java, applet

How to deploy Applets with No Restrictions and/or Full Permissions.

I've attempted to deploy a policy file, I've signed my applets.

My Current issue is with SocketPermissions. I've stated the question here: [AccessControlExceptions with LiveConnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5007724/java-accesscontrolexception-only-with-liveconnect) as well...

Comment: thanks for that. looks like a solution :)

Comment: It seems that when I try to run the doPriviledged... Error: java.lang.SecurityException: class "Post$1" does not match trust level of other classes in the same package

Comment: Any calls to the Applet made with LiveConnect will run with no permissions (as if the applet wasn't signed at all) - that was my real issue...